# My multiple users are reporting crashes but only a few of those get reported in appcenter. Any idea why?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I understand that crash information is reported only when an app is restarted but there seem to be many people who are testing reporting that my app is crashing and I am sure they are trying more than once.

Some random failures get recorded but seems like many do not.

Has anyone else had this issue where users report crashes but then nothing appears in appcenter?

Here is an example of how I record a crash:

```
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex,
                    new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        {"CrossLatestVersion", "Exception"},
                        {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model},
                        {"Exception", ex.ToString()}
                    });
            }
```

Is there a requirement for a crash like this to be thrown for the crash to be recorded or will just having this be sufficient for the error to be reported when the app restarts?

Comment: It's possible the nature of the crash prevented it from capturing a report.  Or that a connectivity issue is preventing it from submitting.  There are APIs you can use to check for prior crashes.  You can also connect with the engineering team by using the "chat" function is appcenter.ms.

Comment: @Jason, what APIs you can use to check for prior crashes are you referring to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin#did-the-app-crash-in-the-previous-session

Comment: Is there a chance for you to reach out to our support team through the chat button on the portal?
Aside from that - code looks fine; The only thing which is worth checking is ex.ToString() - maybe it contains symbols preventing our backend from processing the error correctly?.. Worth investigating.
Also - just to make sure - debugger is not attached, right?